# Javascript fetch api : Can't retrieve some response header

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am using the javascript fetch API to query a cross-domain api using this code :

```
fetch('https://api.com/search?query="2016"').then(function (response) {

  console.log(response.headers.get('Access-Control-Allow-Headers'))

  console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Range'))
  console.log(response.headers.get('Accept-Range'))

  console.log(response.headers.get('Date'))
  console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))
})
```

The response headers are as follow :

```
Accept-Range:cars 300
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Content-Range, Accept-Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, POST, OPTIONS, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Range:0-99/1941
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 12 Jan 2016 12:17:55 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

What is very strange is that only "Content-Type" is working for others i get *null* :

```
null
null
null
null
application/json
```

What do i need to do to retrieve those *null* headers ?

Comment: does the service allow you to access those?

Comment: does the OPTIONS response include those?

Comment: Yes but it is a GET request so i think its not using OPTIONS anyway

Comment: the browser will do an OPTIONS request first.

Comment: I don't see any OPTIONS request in my Chrome developper tool. But even though my nginx server has "add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Date, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Content-Range, Accept-Range';"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Damn i was using 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' instead of 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'

It works now

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

using `CORS` package. and put this parameters:

```
cors({credentials: true, origin: true, exposedHeaders: '*'})
```

like wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64536201/2591785