# Issue with Accessing Headers in JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, cors, http-headers

I've encountered an issue while trying to access headers in JavaScript using the Fetch API. I've thoroughly checked CORS settings and used CORSMiddleware, but it still appears that the headers are somehow restricted.

When I loop through all the headers using response.headers.forEach(), I can only access a limited set of headers. Here's what I get:

[image: limited headers]

However, when inspecting the network tab in DevTools, I can see that there are more headers, including "x-Chat-Id":

[image: Request headers]

I've tried accessing the "x-Chat-Id" header in my code using various cases ("x-chat-id", "X-Chat-Id"), but I keep getting null.

Here's a snippet of my JavaScript code:

```
async function fetchSessionCookie() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(sessionCookieUrl, {
            method: "GET",
            credentials: "same-origin",
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            response.headers.forEach((value, name) => {
                console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
            });

            // Attempt to retrieve the "x-chat-id" header
            const setCookieHeader = response.headers.get("x-chat-id");

            console.log(setCookieHeader);
            if (!setCookieHeader) {
                console.error("Session cookie header 'x-chat-id' not found in the response.");
                return null;
            }

            // Further processing...

        } else {
            console.error("Failed to fetch or create session cookie");
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while fetching or creating session cookie:", error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any insights on why the "x-Chat-Id" header is not accessible in the JavaScript code even though it's present in the network response would be greatly appreciated.

What i've done so far:

1. Checked the CORS and middleware settings in the backend and it looks good.
2. Added expose_headers=["X-Chat-Id"]
3. Added ip:port/filename.html to be exposed to send requests to the backend.
4. Read another thread and some answers: [Javascript fetch api : Can't retrieve some response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743617/javascript-fetch-api-cant-retrieve-some-response-header)